# What is the difference between Warburg effect and Crabtree effect in metabolism?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, pathway

In addition to answering my question, please suggest a good review article that provides comparison of the above effects. Which pathways affect central carbon metabolism to produce these effects? Also, how many unique metabolic effects are known for metabolism in general? Is there a good article which covers such unique aspects of metabolism?

Comment: Your question is quite broad (multiple questions and overall broad nature). Can you please narrow it down a bit so that it is answerable in a few paragraphs at most?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!